# Hubbard Hamiltonian and alternating potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential

I am trying to diagonalize the Hubbard Hamiltonian (for a 1d fermionic chain) with an alternating potential and find its eigenenergies. The given Hamiltonian is the following:
$$
H=t∑_{j=1}^N(c^†_{j+1}c_j+c^†_{j}c_{j+1})+v∑_j(-1)^jc^†_{j}c_j
$$
As a first step, I have replaced the Fourier transform of the raising\lowering operators: 
$$
c_j=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\Sigma_{k\epsilon[-\pi;\pi]}c_ke^{ijk}
$$
And I obtained: 
$$
H=t∑_{k}2\cos(k)(c^†_{k}c_k)+v∑_kc^†_{k}c_{k+\pi}
$$
Then, I must restrict the values of k to $$[-\pi/2;\pi/2]$$
I tried to separate into three intervals and change the index of the sum, but it does not work. Does anyone have any idea?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you try treating the system as an explicitly bipartite lattice? That is:

$$
H = \nu \sum_j \left(c_j^\dagger c_j - d_j^\dagger d_j\right) + t\sum_{\langle ij\rangle} \left(c_i^\dagger d_j + d_j^\dagger c_i\right)
$$

Now, using what you wrote
$$
c_j = \frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\sum_k c_k e^{ijk}\,,
$$
we for the on-site part of the Hamiltonian
$$
H_S = \frac{1}{N}\nu\sum_j\left(\sum_{pk} c^\dagger_p c_k e^{i\left(k-p\right)j} - \sum_{pk} d^\dagger_p d_k e^{i\left(k-p\right)j}\right) = \nu\sum_p \left(c_p^\dagger c_p - d_p^\dagger d_p\right)\,.
$$

Next, we look at the hopping part:
$$
H_h = \frac{1}{N}t\sum_{\langle nm\rangle}\sum_{pk}\left(c_p^\dagger d_k e^{i\left(km - pn\right)}+ d_k^\dagger c_pe^{-i\left(km - pn\right)}\right)
\\
= \frac{1}{N}t\sum_{n}\sum_{pk}\left(c_p^\dagger d_k e^{i\left(k\left(n+1\right) - pn\right)} + c_p^\dagger d_k e^{i\left(k\left(n-1\right) - pn\right)} + d_k^\dagger c_pe^{-i\left(k\left(n+1\right) - pn\right)} + d_k^\dagger c_pe^{-i\left(k\left(n-1\right) - pn\right)} \right)
\\
= \frac{1}{N}t\sum_{n}\sum_{pk}\left(e^{ik}c_p^\dagger d_k e^{i\left(kn - pn\right)} + e^{-ik}c_p^\dagger d_k e^{i\left(kn - pn\right)} + e^{-ik}d_k^\dagger c_pe^{-i\left(kn - pn\right)} + e^{ik}d_k^\dagger c_pe^{-i\left(kn - pn\right)} \right)
\\
= t\sum_{k}\left(e^{ik}c_k^\dagger d_k  + e^{-ik}c_k^\dagger d_k  + e^{-ik}d_k^\dagger c_k + e^{ik}d_k^\dagger c_k \right) = 2t\sum_k\left[\cos\left(k\right)c_k^\dagger d_k + \cos\left(k\right) d_k^\dagger c_k\right]\,.
$$

This leads us to
$$
H = 
\sum_k
\begin{pmatrix}
c_k^\dagger, d_k^\dagger
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\nu&2t\cos k
\\
2t\cos k&-\nu
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
c_k \\ d_k
\end{pmatrix}\,,
$$
which is easily diagonalizable!

Comment: This helped me finding the solution to my problem. Thank you a lot!